ionic 5 Android app upgrade Api level 33 to 34
I have change in config file targetsdkversion = 33 to targetsdkversion = 34 but below issue is occuring.
'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated.
The current default is 'true'.
It has been removed from the current version of the Android Gradle plugin.
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.
I have try to build app with api level 34.
I have need it's build successfully.

can you find out at which place this attribute comes in? Sometimes cordova  platform  remove android and then add again helps...

I am not sure beforehand I would also try updating the gradle versions in android/build.gradle, android/app/build.gradle and android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties.
If that doesn't work I would think that maybe it's time to migrate from cordova to capacitor 5 which currently has targetsdkversion 34.
